# How to add a custom field as metadata when creating a customer with woocommerce api

Tags: python, django, woocommerce, metadata, woocommerce-rest-api

To begin with, I have a field in my model called **afm**.

I find difficulty in posting among with other fields, the value of this field during the procedure of creating a customer.

The procedure of creating an instance of a customer happens from my django application. After creation the instance is also visible (after posting) to the woocommerce --> users section of the administration panel of the website.

The custom meta field has the key : **wholesale_afm**

How is it possible to put this custom field in the data dictionary?
Below is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
def create_woocommerce_client_individually(wcapi,name,surname,username,email,afm):


        data = {

            "first_name": name,    
            "last_name": surname,
            "username": username,
            "email": email,
            "meta":{
            "wholesale_afm":"afm",
            }
            }
        wcapi.post("customers", data).json()
        print("storing the client to woocommerce website...\n")
```

Comment: I don't know woocommerce but since `afm` is one of the parts in your function, shouldn't you just use it the same way as `name` for example? `"wholesale_afm": afm`?

Comment: @dirkgroten I have tried already but the field not updated with the value

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after searching i figured out how to update the value of a custom meta field for a woocommerce product.

The same procedure happens when talking about users(clients).

In the update part , inside the dictionary containing the data, must be added the part :

```
"meta_data": [{"id": cid, "key": "wholesale_afm", "value": afm }],
```

where:

cid: the customer id given to each customer from the woocommerce site

key: the defined key (usually created in the functions.php)

value: the value fetched from the customer record for this field